# En mi bd Postgres se me desconecta de la base de datos pero la session no se cierra

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

Lo que pasa es que al ejecutar una consulta se me desconecta de la bd pero al revisar la sesión se queda activa, es decir, me desconecta pero no mata la sesión. ¿Alguna idea de lo que puedo hacer?

El error que me aparece antes de desconectarme es este:

> server closed the connection unexpectedly this probably means the server terminated abnormally

Comment: Cómo ejecutas la consulta? Desde dónde? Cómo revisas las sesiones activas? Dónde está la BD?

Comment: Utilizo pgAdmin4 
y la bd esta en un servidor linux

Comment: Eso es firewall o mala configuración de red. `listen_address` debe tener `*` para escuchar en todas las interfaces.

Comment: el listen_address ya tenia el * y aun así falla :(